# Including paypal-rest-sdk in html

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to implement `paypal.configure` and `paypal.createCard` functions in this html page (snippet).How do I include 
**/PayPal-node-SDK** (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK) in this file so that I can use these functions `paypal.configure` and `paypal.createCard`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script  src="paypal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .panel {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 2em auto;
    }

    .bootstrap-basic {
        background: white;
    }

    .panel-body {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 2em auto;
    }

    .helper-text {
        color: #8A6D3B;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        height: 12px;
        display: block;
    }

    /* Braintree Hosted Fields styling classes*/
    .braintree-hosted-fields-focused {
        border: 1px solid #0275d8;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, .6);
    }

    .braintree-hosted-fields-focused.focused-invalid {
        border: 1px solid #ebcccc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(100, 100, 0, .6);
    }

    .img-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    }

    .img-container > img {
        margin-top:-50%;
        margin-left:-50%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 670px) {
        .form-group {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .btn {
            white-space: normal;
        }
    }

    .has-error,
    .has-error .help-block,
    .has-error .form-control {
        border : #a94442 1px solid
    }

    .error_span {
        color:#a94442;
        font-size :12px;
    }

    .invisible_custom {
        display : none;
    }

    .visible_custom {
        disblay : block;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt)
    {
        var cardNUmber = $('#card-number');
        if(cardNUmber.val().length>16){
            return false;
        }
//       // cardNUmber.payform('formatCardNumber');
//        if ($.payform.validateCardNumber(cardNUmber.val()) == false) {
//            cardNUmber.addClass('has-error');
//        } else {
//            cardNUmber.removeClass('has-error');
//            cardNUmber.addClass('has-success');
//        }
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    function isNumberKey2(evt)
    {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    function isNumberKey3(evt)
    {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
</script>

<body>
<!--<center><img src = "ring.gif" class="img-container"></center>-->
<!-- Bootstrap inspired Braintree Hosted Fields example -->
<div class="panel panel-default bootstrap-basic" id = "top">
    <div class="alert alert-success invisible_custom" id = "success-toast">
        <strong>Success!</strong> You have successfully added the card.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger invisible_custom" id="failure-toast">
        <strong>Failure!</strong> Error in adding card. Please enter valid card details.
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Enter Card Details</h3>
    </div>
    <form class="panel-body" id="payment-form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-8">
                <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="card-number" placeholder="4111 1111 1111 1111" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" minlength="12" maxlength="19"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-12">Expiration Date</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="expiration-month" placeholder="MM" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" maxlength="2">-->
                        <select class="form-control" id ="exp-month" required>
                            <option disabled value="" selected >Select Month</option>
                            <option value="01">Jan</option>
                            <option value="02">Feb</option>
                            <option value="03">Mar</option>
                            <option value="04">Apr</option>
                            <option value="05">May</option>
                            <option value="06">Jun</option>
                            <option value="07">Jul</option>
                            <option value="08">Aug</option>
                            <option value="09">Sep</option>
                            <option value="10">Oct</option>
                            <option value="11">Nov</option>
                            <option value="12">Dec</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="expiration-year" placeholder="YY" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="2">-->
                        <select class="form-control" id ="exp-year" required>
                            <option disabled value="" selected >Select Year </option>
                            <option value="18"> 2018</option>
                            <option value="19"> 2019</option>
                            <option value="20"> 2020</option>
                            <option value="21"> 2021</option>
                            <option value="22"> 2022</option>
                            <option value="23"> 2023</option>
                            <option value="24"> 2024</option>
                            <option value="25"> 2025</option>
                            <option value="26"> 2026</option>
                            <option value="27"> 2027</option>
                            <option value="28"> 2028</option>
                            <option value="29"> 2029</option>
                            <option value="30"> 2030</option>
                            <option value="31"> 2031</option>
                            <option value="32"> 2032</option>
                            <option value="33"> 2033</option>
                            <option value="34"> 2034</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label">CVV</label>
                <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cvv" placeholder="123" onkeypress="return isNumberKey2(event)" maxlength="4">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="control-label">Card Type</label>
                <!--  Hosted Fields div container -->
                <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" id="postal-code" placeholder="90241"  maxlength="10">-->
                <select class="form-control" id="cardtype" required>
                    <option disabled value="" selected >Select Card Type </option>
                    <option value="visa">Visa </option>
                    <option value="mastercard">MasterCard / Eurocard</option>
                    <option value="maestro">   Maestro</option>
                    <option value="americanexpress">American Express</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>


        <button value="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg center-block">Add  <span id="card-type">Card</span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script src="payform-validation.js"></script>
<script>

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) {
            url = window.location.href;
        }
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    var form = $('#payment-form');
    $('input', form).on('focus', function(){
        $(this).parent().find('.error_span').remove();
        $(this).removeClass("has-error");
    });
    form.submit(function(event) {
//        window.location.href="#top";
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
        var error_message_span = "<span class ='error_span'>* This field is required. </span>"
        form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true);

        if($("#card-number").val() === ""){
            if(!$("#card-number").hasClass("has-error")) {
                $("#card-number").addClass("has-error");
                $("#card-number").parent().append(error_message_span)

            }
        }

        if($("#cvv").val() === "") {
            if(!$("#cvv").hasClass("has-error")) {
                $("#cvv").addClass("has-error");
                $("#cvv").parent().append(error_message_span)
            }

        }

        if($("#exp-month").val() === "") {
            if(!$("#exp-month").hasClass("has-error")) {
                $("#exp-month").addClass("has-error");
                $("#exp-month").parent().append(error_message_span);

            }
        }

        if($("#exp-year").val() === "") {
            if(!$("#exp-year").hasClass("has-error")) {
                $("#exp-year").addClass("has-error");
                $("#exp-year").parent().append(error_message_span);
            }

        }
        if($("#cardtype").val() === "") {
            if(!$("#cardtype").hasClass("has-error")) {
                $("#cardtype").addClass("has-error");
                $("#cardtype").parent().append(error_message_span);
            }

        }

        if ($('#card-number').val() === "" || $('#cvv').val() === "" || $('#exp-month').val() === "" || $('#exp-year').val() === "" || $('#cardtype').val() === "") {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert(window["paypal"]);
            console.log('asdfadsf',$('#cardtype').val());
            paypal.configure({
                'mode'         : '<%= mode %>',      //sandbox or live 
                'client_id'    : '<%= client_id %>',
                'client_secret': '<%= client_secret %>'
               });
            // Create customer card Paypal
             paypal.creditCard.create({
                number: $('#card-number').val(),
                cvv2: $('#cvv').val(),
                expire_month: $('#exp-month').val(),
                expire_year: $('#exp-year').val(),
                type : $('#cardtype').val()
            }, function(error, response){
                if (error || !response) {
                    $('#success-toast').hide();
                    $("#failure-toast").show();
                    window.location.href="#top";
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#failure-toast').hide();
                    },3500);
                    return false;
                } 
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: window.location.origin + "/add_merchant_card",
                        type: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            access_token    :    getParameterByName('access_token'),
                            app_device_type :    getParameterByName('app_device_type'),
                            card_details: {
                                customer_id    : response.id,
                                last4_digits   : response.number,
                                brand          : response.type,
                                expiry_date    : response.expire_month + "/" + response.expire_year 
                            },
                            payment_method: 32
                        }),
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).success(function (data) {
                        var body = data; //JSON.parse(data);
                        if (body.status == 'ok') {
                            window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/success.html");
                        }
                        else {
                            window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/error.html");
                       }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        // Prevent the form from being submitted:
        return false;
    });

  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: That SDK is for Node.js, JavaScript for servers. Not sure if there is one for browsers.

Comment: But if I add a file paypal.js where 
var paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk') 
and use <script src=paypal.js> in html file @yuriy636

Comment: It won't work. The SDK isn't designed for browsers, it uses Node.js methods. I think you are looking for the REST API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Comment: I can implement it on server side and it will work fine but then I have to fetch all the credit card related information on server (not store them) which is somewhat not secure though from that information I generate card id for future transaction,so I was implementing fetching card details on client  side @yuriy636